# XAMPP and Windows Server 2016

Tags: xampp

I am currently looking at acquiring a new server. I was looking at Windows Server 2016 as the operating system. Is there any issues running the latest version of xampp under Windows Server 2016?

Answer (score 1):

I have installed XAMPP version 3.2.2 on  Windows Server 2016 and everything is going well.
The only problem which i have faced is the port 443 which is being in used so If you are using IIS you need to change the default ports in XAMPP (80 in httpd.conf and 443 in httpd-ssl.conf).